# What does stateless RESTful API actually mean?

Tags: angular, rest

In normal `stateful` API html pages are returned, whereas in Angular each request to back-end returns a JavaScript object instead. Does only that fact make the back-end `stateless`? If not, what does `stateless` term actually mean? For example, in Angular authentication, a token is returned, and that token is used to authorize each request to a back-end. What makes the back-end `stateless` in this example?

Comment: Stateless has nothing to do with HTML vs. JSON. It means that the server doesn't keep any state in memory about your conversation, i.e. previous requests. For example, it doesn't have a session containing your personal details, or what you stored in a basket in previous requests. Being stateless makes it more scalable. First because it doesn't need more memory to store more user information, second because you can have a cluster of servers handling requests, and every server is able to handle any request, since none of them needs to keep state.

Comment: @JBNizet In short, as the server does not depend on a previous request, it does not keep a variable. Hence, there is no state at the server side, it basically handles requests like functions which clear  all the work after itself. When there is at least one variable changed after a request, and this variable may influence some future request, then this is a gamechanger, so a state is supported, or a session to be precious. Is that correct?

Comment: I wouldn't use the same terminology as yours, but yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does stateless RESTful API actually mean?

[Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is an important REST constraint, and means something precise:

> each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.
>
> ...
>
> Scalability is improved because not having to store state between requests allows the server component to quickly free resources, and further simplifies implementation because the server doesn't have to manage resource usage across requests.

[Cookies](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4_2), for example, are not stateless.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant when saying Cookies, for example, are not stateless?

Answer (score 6):

It's not what it returns that makes it `stateless`. `RESTful` api's by definition are meant to be stateless. It doesnt store any state about the clients session or  know about any prior requests that has been made. Each new request is handled in isolation. No `'state'` is preserved like; Is this user authorized or authenticated. The `client` has to send all neccessary information with each request.

Answer (score 0):

imagine you are on your way for work and your office is in some floor of a certain building.

upon entry, you encounter a security guard who asks for your company id to verify your identity. you showed it to him and got in.

the very next day, on the way for work, same thing happens.

you've been doing this for a long time. and every time you try to get into the building, you get asked your identity. the security definitely knows you but still asks for your identity.

this is **statelessness**.